# New Nginx Site-Path not showing : conflicting server name

Tags: nginx, configuration, webserver

I currently have one domain, and trying to host two paths: `domainB.com`, and `domainB.com/blog` on my server.

Im looking to visit `domainB.com/blog` and make this into a `blog`, but when i try to do this I get an error of:

```
2016/12/14 16:33:45 [warn] 1026#0: conflicting server name "domainB.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2016/12/14 16:33:46 [error] 1039#0: *1 open() "/home/www/flask-deploy/blog/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 195.154.199.56, server: domainB.com, request: "GET /license.php HTTP/1.0", host: "www.domainB.com"
2016/12/14 16:34:31 [error] 1039#0: *10 directory index of "/home/www/flask-deploy/blog/" is forbidden, client: xxx.xx.xx.xxx, serve
```

**UPDATED - how does this config look??**

```
upstream siteb {
    server http://localhost:8001;
}

upstream siteb-blog {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name siteb.com;

    root /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb;

    location / {
        #proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_pass siteb;
    }

    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/siteB/static/;
    }


    location ~* ^/blog/ {
    root /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb-blog;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass siteb-blog;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to visit: `siteB.com/blog` - I get a `404 error`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: `nginx` cannot have two `server` blocks with the same `server_name` and port. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: @RichardSmith How do you resolve? so, would i need to add them in the same config and make `1` have `server_name` `domainB.com` and `2` have `server_name` `domainB.com/blog` ?

Comment: @RichardSmith - please provide an answer with an example please. this document you provided is difficult to understand for my situation

Answer (score 0):

Like @RichardSmith said, you can't have 2 server blocks with the same server_name. Only the first one will be loaded.

The only way to fix your problem is to merge all into 1 config file and use location for your blog.

I have this working like this:

```
upstream siteb {
    #flask app
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

upstream siteb-blog {
    #wordpress php
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name siteb.com;
    root /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb/;

    location ~* ^/blog/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass siteb-blog;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files @proxy @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://siteb;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

This is an example with 2 different backends.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is helpful, albeit a bit __confusing__ . What is the block `location ~ \.php?` used for? My `flask-web` application is not php based.

Comment: @Raul- please see my updated code. How does it look from a configuration point of view?

Comment: Your original config had the unix php sock in it. You don't need that php location if your stuff is not php of course, you can just do ```location /```

Comment: My stuff is php will be a wordpress blog. `siteb.com` is a python/flask app. How can I modify my config to fit this? Current one is updated in my question. Thanks @Raul

Comment: this is much better, albeit, when i try to view `siteb.com/blog/index.php` for example it says: `No input file specified` on the browser? Thoughts?

Comment: Some quick research said it might be a problem with: `SCRIPT_FILENAME` - thoughts with this??

Comment: So, couple of things: 1) are you sure your files are in /home/www/flask-deploy/siteb/blog 2) add in that location `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;` 3)post your error_log pls